# How can one estimate the transaction throughput of a substrate chain?

Tags: transactions

I am interested in measuring/estimating the transaction throughput of my chain. How should I start?

Comment: Depends on how the topology of your chain looks like. Does it have parachains? Multiple nodes? We are working on a general way to benchmark various chain setups, but that could take another month or two.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi for now I am running 2 nodes and it's a solo chain so no parachains.

Answer (score 5):

You should start by benchmarking the extrinsics defined in your runtime. See [here](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/benchmarking/) to learn how to do this.

The benchmarks will give you an execution weight in units of picoseconds, ie. `1_000_000_000_000` weight units ~ 1 second of execution time. Note the result of this depends on the hardware you run the benchmarks on - you should benchmark on a machine that matches your recommended validator hardware specs.

A typical extrinsic executed on typical hardware might weigh `200_000_000` units, equivalent to 200 microseconds. So in this case you could estimate a transaction throughput of `1_000_000 ms / 200 ms per tx ~ 5000 tx`.

There are other considerations, for example this rough estimation doesn't take into account the pallet hooks and other work that needs to be performed to process a block (see [here](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/benchmarking/#minimize-usage-of-on_finalize-and-transition-logic-to-on_initialize)). So the value calculated above should be considered an upper bound.

Also your runtime likely defines more than a single extrinsic, so you would also need to estimate the relative frequency of each extrinsic to get a more accurate picture.